# Is it possible to cache the application jar when running Apache Spark applications on a cluster?

Tags: java, caching, apache-spark, mesos

I've got an Apache Spark MLlib Java application that should be run on a cluster a lot of times with different input values. Is it possible to cache the application jar on the cluster and reuse it to reduce startup time, network load and coupling of components?

Does the used cluster manager make any difference?

If the application jar is cached, is it possible to use the same RDD caches in different instances of my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vainilla Spark is not able to do this (at the time of writing - Spark is evolving fast) .

There's a Spark-JobServer contributed by Ooyala that exactly fulfills your needs. It keeps a register with the jars for sequential job submission and provides additional facilities to cache RDDs by name.  Note that on a Spark Cluster, the Spark-JobServer acts as a Spark driver. The workers will still need to load the jars from the driver when going to execute a given task.

See docs here: https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver

Comment: The spark-jobserver looks great, but is Java supported? The docs say: "Jobs submitted to the job server must implement a SparkJob" which is a Scala trait. To use NamedRDDs you have to use NamedRddSupport trait. Is this usable from Java? Will I have to use to Scala?

Comment: SparkJob is a simple trait that you could use as an interface from Java. That should be OK. The NamedRDDSupport is a mixin with a self-type. I'm not sure how that plays from Java. Probably creating a base class in scala `class BaseNamedRDDSparkJob extends SparkJob with NamedRDDSupport` and extending that from Java could work for you. But of course I'm going to tell you to use Scala :-)

Comment: This might have worked but I rewrote my prototype. There is a bit of a showstopper though: https://github.com/ooyala/spark-jobserver/issues/5

Comment: @Wienczny you mean the jar size?  That's no show stopper. Changing the spray-can config fixes that.  We upload jars of about 100Mb.